# mysql_real_escape_string not taking care of single quote

Tags: php, mysql, database, escaping

I've tried it this way:

```
$desc = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['description'][$i]);
```

and then tried inserting the variable `$desc` into MySQL and I've tried:

```
'".mysql_real_escape_string($desc)."'
```

as part of the actual insert query. Neither one works.

I get `1x10-10` instead of `1x10-10'` pine.

Everything gets cut off at the first single quote. I even tried:

```
$desc = mysql_real_escape_string("1x10-10' pine")`
```

to see what would happen and that worked with the slash being added in.

Any suggestions?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Is your MySQL-field long enough to take the whole string?

Comment: How does the resulting statement look like. Please provide the full statement or at least the context this piece of code is used in.

Comment: htmlspecialchars cannot mess up the query. this function intended for HTML output, not SQL

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it's not mysql_real_escape_string nor SQL, but rather your HTML responsible for that behavior.

Be sure you're printing tag attributes using `htmlspecialchars` with `ENT_QUOTES` flag.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, I too believe it's the HTML on the page being sent to the process page. The suggestion to use htmlspecialchars with ENT_QUOTES flag messes up the query, so I'm rebuilding both pages and will check back later with results. Thanks